# Remove accepted self-signed certificate from iOS Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, mobile-safari, certificate

I was experimenting with self-signed certificates and while viewing my website from Safari on an iPhone I first got the warning that it is an untrusted site and I could review the details of the certificate. I then tapped the "Accept" button in the top right corner and continued to browse the site. Now Safari is not asking me again when visiting my site. No matter if I clear history or go to Safari settings and choose *Clear Cookies and Data* and even If I restart my phone.

Obviously there is an option to completely reset all iPhone settings but that is highly inconvenient to just remove a certificate you no longer need.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to remove that particular certificate?

Comment: did you look for it in your keychain ?

Comment: I do not use iCloud keychain. So is there a place or method on the iPhone to view its built-in keychain?

Comment: Settings -> General -> Profiles

Comment: Not there... :-/ I only see "iOS Team Provisioning" listed there.